# New Android App ( Xamarin) targeting Android 9.0 api not compiling because missing Android X assemblies (but they need Android 11.0 version)

Tags: android, xamarin, version, nuget-package, androidx

I am trying to build an Android app to make a simple prototype. Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (v17.2.4), I create an Android App (Xamarin), blank app. And I target Android 9.0 version.

But, I have compilation errors :

Could not find 2 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages:

- Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData
- Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser

Problem is that I can't install these NuGet packages because they need Android 12.0 version or greater :

Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData 2.5.1 is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData 2.5.1 supports:

- monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0)
- net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

So I don't know how to solve this. I don't want to target Android 12 version, I need this app to launch on an Android 9.0 device.
What are these libraries the app need to compile? Can I do without them? I don't find any references to them.

Note : I have a warning too on the same way, but not sure if it has to deal with my compilation issue. I Put it anyway, if it can help :

Warning     Google Play requires that new applications and updates must use a TargetFrameworkVersion of v11.0 (API level 30) or above. You are currently targeting v9.0 (API level 28).

Please, any idea to solve my issue?
I just want to compile and launch an Android (Xamarin) blank app targeting Android 9.0.

Thank you and have a good day,

Comment: If you must use these package, you need update to android 12. Otherwise you need to delete the package and use another one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding this a problem too. Just deployed an app (Dec 2022) that targeted 28 / 12 and has min version 10 as appears enforced by Google?

Prob is I've got a lot of people wanting to use the app that can't see it because they have ancient phones (9 or earlier - is that 5 years or more). Seems a bit tough? Is there a way to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the today's Xamarin Android project templates are designed to compile with Android 12. I don't think there is a way to build them with Android 9.

I guess we just have to find another older template?
For my part I had finally took an older project I had instead of creating a new project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33518875)